# How to get char from button to edit text?

Tags: java, android

> this code work very well its generate three button because I have three elements"car" and shuffle elements
>       button_1 "a" ,   button_2 "r" ,  button_3 "c" , my problem is when I click on every button its typing
>   in edit text became "a a a"

```
//the problem was here (var button)

    edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString() + button.getText());
```

> i am trying to make game guessing the word

```
    String array[]= {"car"};


    int random = (int) (Math.random() * array.clone().length);

    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(array[random]);


    for (int i = 0; i < array[random].length(); i++) {

        char id = 'b';
        final Button button = new Button(this); //local var
        button.setId(id + i);
        linearLayout.addView(button);


        int randIndex = new Random().nextInt(word.length());
        button.setText("" + word.charAt(randIndex));
        word.deleteCharAt(randIndex);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //******the problem was here (var button)

                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString() + button.getText());
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: try to remove `onClickListener` from **loop**

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'button'

Comment: Let me confirm my understanding of the requirement. If I understood it correctly, when you click the buttons labelled, `a`, `c`, and `r` one by one, `edittext` should display `a`, then `ac` and finally `acr`. Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: my code generate three buttons and each of these button get char from index of array my index is "CAR" button_1 get char "A" , button_2 get char "R" , button_3 get char "C" ,

Comment: when I click on button_1 edite text get "A" my problem  button_2 edite text get "A"  button_3 edite text get "A"

Comment: Can you put `System.out.println(button.getText());` before `edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString() + button.getText());` and check what does it print?

Comment: System.out.println does not work in indroid studio